# SYNC13C SPOJ Wrong answer

Tags: c, algorithm

[Link to challenge](http://www.spoj.com/problems/SYNC13C/)

> Ramesh and Suresh get a box full of five stars on lottery each. Since
>   both the boxes need not have the same number of chocolates, they
>   decide to play a game. The winner gets to have both the boxes of
>   chocolates. They play alternatively and Suresh starts the game. Given
>   the number of chocolates in both the boxes, let them be c1 and c2, the
>   player takes either c1 or c2 number of chocolates and divide the
>   remaining box of chocolates to two boxes (these two boxes need not
>   have the same number of chocolates). The player who cannot make such a
>   move loses. Input
>
> First line of input contains a number T(1<=T<=1000), the number of
>   test cases. Then follows T lines each containing two space separated
>   integers c1 and c2
>
> (1<=c1<=c2<=10000).
>
> Output For each test case print "Ramesh" or "Suresh" depending on who
>   is the winner.
>
> Input: 2 3 1 4 5
>
> Output: Ramesh Suresh

Here is my attempt, which is giving me the wrong answer.  Give me some more test cases, too.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t,c1,c2,max,count,min;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d%d",&c1,&c2);
        min=c1<c2?c1:c2;  
        max=c1>c2?c1:c2;
        if(max%2!=0 && min%2!=0) 
            printf("Ramesh\n");
        else if(min%2==0 && max%2!=0)
            printf("Suresh\n");
        else if(max%2==0 && min%2!=0)
            printf("Ramesh\n");  
        else printf("Suresh\n");
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Intersting one. One thing is certain: you dont use `if else if` but some recursive algorithm. For example, you take the c1-1 numbers which are < c1 and make all posible pairs adding to c1. For c1 = 5 you have 1,2,3,4 so 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-3, 2-4, 3-4 and keep 1-4 and 2-3. Then you do the same recursively. Just a first thought. Btw i like maths!

Answer (score 3):

The code is much simpler than that. First, let me explain the algorithm.

Let `W` be an array where,

`W[i] = 1 if the user wins by choosing to split the box of i chocolates and 0 if he looses.`

Lets construct this array and we will be getting a pattern.

`W[1] = 0, since one can't split the box of one chocolate.`

For all `i>1`, we have:

> `W[i]` = 1 if there exists integers `a` and `b` such that `a+b=i` and `W[a]=W[b]=0` , `0` otherwise.

The above statement implies that, for a user to win by choosing the `i` chocolate box, he needs make sure that, his opponent looses no matter what box he chooses further. His opponent loosing implies that `W[a]=W[b]=0` and `a+b=i`.

If we try to fill up this array we get,

> W : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7...
>
> val: 0 1 0 1 0 1 0...

This means if one the given integers is `even`, then suresh is going to win. If both of them are `odd`, it means ramesh will win.

Hope I am clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
       int a,b;
       scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
       if(a%2==1 && b%2==1)
           printf("Ramesh\n");
       else
           printf("Suresh\n");
    }    
    return 0;
}
```